# Deploy pure Elixir app on Heroku or other hosting services

Tags: heroku, elixir

I've just made a pure elixir app which generates a random image based on the text user inputs. I do not have any front-end for this and fully rely on terminal to input a text to the app.

I know how to make a Phoenix app using Elixir and deploy it on Heroku or other hosting services. But I wonder if it's possible to deploy a pure Elixir app (not relying on any framework like Phoenix).

Please correct me if I'm wrong for asking this question.

Comment: How do you want to run the application after putting it on Heroku? You need some kind of HTTP server if you want to be able to access it from an HTTP URL.

Comment: How do you suppose this application to be run on heroku in the first place?

Comment: What purpose would deploying it to a web host serve?

Answer (score -1):

For a CLI application, you can package it as an escript: [Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/master/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html)

This gives you an application with a `main/1` entry point.

mix.exs:

```
defmodule MyApp.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :my_app,
      version: "0.0.1",
      escript: escript()
    ]
  end

  def escript do
    [main_module: MyApp.CLI]
  end
end
```

lib/my_app/cli.ex:

```
defmodule MyApp.CLI do
  def main(_args) do
    IO.puts("Hello from MyApp!")
  end
end
```

Comment: After packaging the CLI application with an escript, is it possible to deploy the app to hosting services like Heroku? My instinct is that this app will be just local. Please correct me if I'm mixing up some stuff.

Comment: Not sure how well supported CLI apps are on heroku, I thought the platform was oriented around web applications.